# How to call a shortcode with ajax in WordPress to show an Elementor template?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, shortcode

I would like to use ajax to call a shortcode to display an Elementor template. The template shortcode is: [elementor-template id="1008"]

This is the Ajax I am trying to use:

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'https://somedomain.com.au/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        cache: false,
        data : { 'action': 'elementor-template', 'id': '1008' },
        complete : function() {  },
        success: console.log(data),
        error: console.log(error)
    });
```